# drawWithRect crashing with an exception breakpoint on iOS 8 (Does not crash without exception breakpoint)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, drawrect, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Happy iPhone Day everyone! I hope everyone managed to get their hands on one.

I have a strange issue. In my code, I have a `UITableView` and if the user selects the Email icon in the `UINavigationBar`, it does two things:

1) Opens up the `MFMailComposer`

2) Creates a PDF in the background of the contents of the `UITableView` and attaches it to the email

This has so far been working very well in iOS 7. With iOS 8, if I set an exception breakpoint in my code and run it on an iOS 8 device, it will crash when I click the email icon (iPhone 5s), pointing to the code below:

```
    [strheader drawWithRect:CGRectMake(65, -670, 1024, 100) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:headerFont} context:nil];
```

It doesn't let me jump in or out of this breakpoint or do anything to find out what's going on. If I remove the Exception breakpoint, there's no crash. If I run the app on my device and disconnect the device from Xcode, run it again, there's no crash.

So ultimately, there's no crash when running my app, but it makes me extremely nervous that with an exception breakpoint, it crashes at that code above which means something isn't right somewhere.

There are no warnings in my code. The method that does the saving of the PDF to the email (which contains that code) is extremely long; if it's required, I'll paste it here but I don't want to make this question longer than it needs to be.

If I remove the exception breakpoint from that line and just set a regular breakpoint, as expected, it stops at that point. I run through and there are no errors at all. If I run through the whole breakpoint, it does what it needs to and then shows the `MFMailComposer` in the App. So it's not actually "crashing", but the exception breakpoint clearly has a problem with it.

How can I find out WHY it's crashing? More importantly, how can I fix it? (which will probably only be answerable after the first question gets answered).

Comment: This is a guess.  You may be breaking on a throw for some exception that is being caught and handled.  If you change your exception to break on catch, do you see it being caught?  (If you do, then it doesn't sound like anything you'd need to worry about.)

Comment: Thanks so much @PhillipMills - I really appreciate the response. I'll admit, that whole area of breakpoints being set to break on catch / throw is new to me in terms of understanding what it does, but I changed my exception breakpoint to Break on Catch, ran the code again and it did the same thing. So does that mean it's all good? I rather concentrate of implementing features, especially because I can't get this to crash without the breakpoint? Thanks again

Comment: @Lavanya: I'm having exactly the same issue right now. Did you find a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: Instead of switching from "Break On Throw" to "Break On Catch", I switched my exception breakpoint from catching all exceptions to just catching Objective-C exceptions, and the breakpoint no longer got tripped up. This suggests that the exception is being thrown (and then subsequently caught) in some C++ code somewhere.

Comment: Gabe is right! The exception seems to be thrown (and been caught) somewhere in the foundation code. Changing the 'All Exceptions' to 'All Objective-C Exceptions' (right click, 'Edit breakpoint', 'Exception' from 'All' to  'Objective-C') removed this annoying exception.